# IIS receiving hostname differs from website certificate error after importing .pfx

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

I copied a wildcard certificate from an apache server to a windows server.
Using openssl i was able to create the .pfx file.  I imported this pfx into MMC certificate console on the windows server.  The certificate imported fine and has the key icon indicating valid.
I added the certificate to a website and i'm receiving the following browser error when i try to access that website:

> The hostname in the website’s security certificate differs from the
>   website you are trying to visit.  Error Code:
>   DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID

The common name of the certificate is *.mydomain.com.

The website host name is in this format sd1.sd2.mydomain.com

The windows server is a virtual machine hosted on Azure.
What can cause this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: In IIS, how did you configure your bindings?  For instance, do you just have default [*] or do you also have one-or-more bindings that match your cert's pattern?

Comment: I have two bindings set.  One for HTTP and one for HTTPS.  Same hostname is used for both and it does match the patter of the cert.

Comment: The `*` in the cert's domain name only serves as a wildcard for a single level of the name.  So `*.mydomain.com` matches `sd2.mydomain.com` and `sd1.mydomain.com`, but it does not match `sd1.sd2.mydomain.com`.  (It also does not match `mydomain.com`.). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) for more info.

Comment: Do you have the option to create a DNS entry to match your cert? Like maybe sd1sd2.mydomain.com. Probably cheaper & more simple than getting certs to match your server naming pattern.

Comment: @ottomeister - this should be an answer. It explains why there is an error.